# why do I get this mail server configuration error?

Tags: email, smtp, configuration

```
<<The configuration of your mail servers and your DNS are not ok! The report of the test is:

    mail.mydomain.com. -> mydomain.com -> 78.47.63.148 -> static.148.63.47.78.clients.your-server.de

Spam recognition software and RFC821 4.3 (also RFC2821 4.3.1) state that the hostname given in the SMTP greeting MUST have an A record pointing back to the same server.>>
```

I have a A Record that points mail.mydomain.com to 78.47.63.148 (which is my given ip address for my vps)
All other records are fine, so what's wrong and what record should I create to make it right?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your server identifies itself as mail.mydomain.com in its SMTP greeting then the reverse DNS for your ip needs to be mail.mydomain.com. At the moment it's that static.xxx name.

You'll need to get your provider to change your reverse DNS or change you mail server to identify itself as static.148.63.47.78.clients.your-server.de. That static name should also have an A record pointing to the IP if you change the greeting, which it probably already does.

Comment: identify itself as "static.148.63.47.78.clients.your-server.de" is a bad idea, many spamfilters would block that due to a generic rDNS HELO. changing the reverse DNS to mail.mydomain.com is the only option that will make all other servers happy.